# Migrating old customer cards to sources in stripe

Tags: stripe-payments, payment-processing, 3d-secure

Is there a way we can migrate the existing Cards attached to customers on stripe to Sources. We already have a user base who have their payment methods added to our system using the old stripe cards and we don't want them to remove their payment methods.

The issue is that when implementing 3D secure with stripe, the old cards added to stripe do not return extra information that is provided by the sources object such as the `three_d_secure` field. Is there a way to migrate them to Sources and get that extra information about those cards ?

**Some technical details (might be irrelevant)**

We were creating payment sources in the following way.

```
customer = stripe.Customer.retrieve(customer_id)
source = customer.sources.create(card=card_token)
```

When attaching a source to a customer, We were using `card=card_token` instead of `source=card_token` which creates a Card object on stripe instead of a Source object.